# `undefined method `default_timezone=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class` on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu 14.04 instance to host a rails 4.2 application that I'm developing, but I keep hitting this same error, no matter how ruby/rails are installed. I'm using ruby 2.2.0, and rails 4.2.0

When I try to run any command that initialises rails, I get the following exception:

```
undefined method `default_timezone=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class
```

This occurs when using ruby installed via the `brightbox/ruby-ng` apt repository, and when installed via `rbenv` and `ruby-build`. The application doesn't have this error with the same versions of ruby/rails installed on my OS X 10.10.2 machine.

Here's the full stack trace when running `$ bin/rake db:migrate --trace`:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `default_timezone=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:71:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:69:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
[redacted project dir]/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:443:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

I've tried setting `config.time_zone` and `config.active_record.default_timezone` in my `config/application.rb` file, but neither helped.

Does anyone have any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: What does your `database.yml` look like?

Comment: What did you try setting `config.time_zone` and `active_record.default_timezone` to?

Comment: Show your `config/environment.rb`

Comment: It turns out that it was the DATABASE_URL environment variable that caused this issue. I have a password with special characters and because they weren't url escaped, it errored like this.